# how to delete reduplicate element in an array in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, delete-row

I have a two column array, which is already sorted according to the first column. I want to remove some elements according my rule:

1) compare the value the element with all the other values in the first column.  If the difference of the value with others is larger than a given value (0.1 for example), keep it in the new array. Otherwise, if the data whose difference with others is smaller than the value, all of these value  could be regarded as a compare group, then

2) for these compare groups, I need compare their elements in the second column and retain only the elements with the smallest value in second column in the groups.

For example: if my array is

```
 a= [[1.2, 3], 
     [2.2, 3], 
     [2.25, 1], 
     [2.28, 3], 
     [3.2, 8], 
     [4.2, 10]]
```

Then what I want to get is following:

```
  a=[[1.2, 3],  
     [2.25, 1], 
     [3.2, 8], 
     [4.2, 10]]
```

I delete the second and fourth elements. because the difference of the first elements 2.2,2.25 and 2.28 are smaller than 0.1, but the second elements 1 is the smallest one among them.

Could some one give me some hints, please?
thanks

Comment: may need to define your case a little more closely... i.e. if your limit is 0.1, and you have 2.19, 2.23, 2.27, 2.31, are 2.19 and 2.31 both in your compare group?

Comment: @Corley Brigman, yes, you are right! If it is the case you said, all of them are in the compare group and maintain only one in the end. I will define the question much clearer!thanks

Comment: how strict are your requirements? the way you described it, this is a very long running O(n**2) problem, since you have to compare every element against every other element. i may have a relatively concise solution for you, however, it will probably be pretty slow.

Comment: actually, it's more complicated than i thought. was thinking of using a graph, but think the algorithm ends up being the same.

Comment: @Corley Brigman, Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me your algorithm? The speed is not so important for my case, because in my array there are not more than 10 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from numpy import *

eps = 0.1
#ASSUMING the second arrow is sorted (otherwise sort it first)
a= array(
    [[1, 1.2, 3],     
    [2, 2.2, 3], 
    [3, 2.25, 1], 
    [4, 2.28, 4],
    [5, 3.2, 8], 
    [6, 4.2, 10],
    [7, 4.21, 3], 
    [8, 4.25, 4], 
    [9, 4.28, 1],
    [10, 5.2, 10],
    ])
# expected result
# a= [[1, 1.2, 3],
#     [3, 2.25, 1],
#     [5, 3.2, 8],
#     [9, 4.28, 1],
#     [10, 5.2, 10],
#     ]

n = shape(a)[0]
b = a[:,1]

a1 = a[ (diff(b)<eps) ]
#indexes of some False that could be True.
#these indexes should be checked backwards
#and evtl. added to a1
indexes = where((diff(b)<eps)==False)[0][1:]
for index in indexes:
    if b[index] - b[index-1]<eps:
        a1 = vstack( (a1,a[index,:]) )

#sort array
a1 = a1[lexsort( (a1[:,1],a1[:,1]))]

groups = where(diff(a1[:,1])>eps)[0]
i = 0
# get min of groups
for g in groups:
    ag = a1[i:g+1,2]
    Ag = a1[i:g+1,:]
    if i == 0:
        a2 = Ag [ ag == min(ag) ]
    else:
        a2 = vstack( (a2, Ag [ ag == min(ag) ] ) )

    i = g+1
#add last group
ag = a1[g+1:,2]
Ag = a1[g+1:,:]    
a2 = vstack( (a2, Ag [ ag == min(ag) ]) )

#the elements that build no groups
result = a[ in1d(a[:,0], [ int(i) for i in a[:,0] if i not in a1[:,0] ])  ] 
# add the elements of a2, these are the minimal elements of each group
result = vstack( (result, a2) )
# sort the result (optional)
result = result[lexsort( (result[:,0], result[:,0]))]
print "final result\n", result
```

Here is the output of this code

```
In [1]: run filter.py
final result
[[  1.     1.2    3.  ]
 [  3.     2.25   1.  ]
 [  5.     3.2    8.  ]
 [  9.     4.28   1.  ]
 [ 10.     5.2   10.  ]]
```